# Azure App Service internal service error after putting 350 IP Addresses in "ipSecurityRestrictions"

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, ip-address, azureportal

What is the maximum number of IP Addresses that we can put in the **"ipRestrictions"** section of the `web.config` inside Azure Resource Explorer?

Currently, we have to whitelist 350 IP addresses that should be able to access the App Service. However, after putting the IP addresses the App Service causes an internal server error possibly due to the number of IP Addresses. What is the workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a try to do it with the azure resource (https://resources.azure.com) WebsiteName->config->web->ipSecurityRestrictions. We could add the value as following then put the http request. I try to add more than 350 ipAddress, it still works well. More detial steps please refer to another [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41958723/how-to-restrict-access-to-an-app-service-using-a-setting-inside-the-azure-portal?answertab=active#tab-top).

```
ipSecurityRestrictions": [
      {
        "ipAddress": "x.x.x.x",
        "subnetMask": "x.x.x.x"
      },
      {
        "ipAddress": "x.x.x.x",
        "subnetMask": "x.x.x.x"
      }
     ....
   ]
```