# Azure Application Gateway locked down route to app service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-gateway

I have setup an azure application gateway with web application firewall to route traffic to an azure app service. This requires setting up a VPN. I have followed instructions similar to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-web-app-powershell

However it doesn't explain how to limit traffic to the app service only via the application gateway.

If I go into app service networking tab there is an option to use VNet integration . I thought this might be a way to lock down access through the gateway to the app service but I can't select the gateway VPN because azure tells me 'This virtual network has no gateway'.

So how to I lock down access to the app service so that only traffic which comes through the gateway can access it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added the following to my ARM template to set up the web.config for the app service:

```
{
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
      "name": "[variables('website_config')]",
      "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
     ....
        "ipSecurityRestrictions": [
          {
            "ipAddress": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', variables('publicIPAddressName'))).IpAddress]",
            "subnetMask": "255.255.255.255"
          }
          ] 
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('websites_name'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', variables('publicIPAddressName'))]"
      ]
     },
```

The resource public IP addresses is the one set up by the gateway

I can no longer access the app service using the url http://.azurewebsites.net which is what I want. Initially when I accessed the public IP address I get the error message: "502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server." however after a bit it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

> So how to I lock down access to the app service so that only traffic which comes through the gateway can access it?

Per my understanding, you could do nothing with [Application Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-introduction). But you could leverage [IP and Domain Restrictions for azure web sites](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/ip-and-domain-restrictions-for-windows-azure-web-sites/) for allowing the traffic comes through your application gateway to access your azure web app. Here is a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41958723/how-to-restrict-access-to-an-app-service-using-a-setting-inside-the-azure-portal). For a simple way, you could log into azure portal, choose your web app, click "SETTING > Networking" and click **Configure IP Restrictions** under IP Restrictions section for adding your custom IP Restrictions.

Comment: Ok, so that allows me to block IP addresses. How do I enable it for a single (or maybe 2 IP addresses)?

Comment: You could control the set of IP addresses, and address ranges. You could click the **Add** button under the **IP Restrictions** blade on Azure portal for adding multiple IP addresses. Here is a configuration sample under the config file, you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/security/ipSecurity/#configuration).

Answer (score 0):

In Azure Portal go to the "Access Restriction" of your Web service.
Then choose to access the application only from VNet and subnet where your application gateway resides.
[image]