# Locking down Azure App service access to a set of IP adresses. Security advice needed

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-gateway

I'm trying to secure access to a very simple app running in an Azure App Service. This app accepts HTTP POST requests (HTTPS unavailable) from a vendor and writes the output to Azure Queue Storage.

Currently I'm using an inbound traffic restriction to whitelist the vendor's IP ranges. In terms of security, am I better off putting the app behind an Application Gateway with WAF enabled?

I've also looked at the possibility of adding a Service Endpoint, then using a DNAT rule on the Azure Firewall to redirect traffic but am unsure if this would be sufficient either.

Any advice would be most appriciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***To restrict the set of IP address to Azure Web App Service, please try the below as mentioned in this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions#set-a-service-endpoint-based-rule):***

*Go to Azure Portal -> App Services -> Select your App -> Networking -> Add rule*

[image]

**Otherwise**, you can add a routing rule as mentioned in this [**blog**](https://www.patrickob.com/2019/02/20/app-service-w-app-gateway-v2-high-security-in-azure-paas/) by Patrick like below:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Application Gateway -> Your Application Gateway -> Rules -> Add a routing rule*

[image]

Please **refer** the below links which might give you a pointer to solve the issue:

[Azure Application Gateway locked down route to app service by johnstaveley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45979433/azure-application-gateway-locked-down-route-to-app-service)

[azure-docs/app-service-ip-restrictions.md by Mads Damgård](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions.md)