# PHP (or whatever) CGI configuration in web.config IIS

Tags: php, iis, wix, cgi, fastcgi

I recently developed an installer for a web application (Yes, Web Application with an Installer) using [Wix Tool Set](http://wixtoolset.org/).

The wizard guides the user to obtain all the basic information the site need for the installation, and looks like below:

[image]

Using custom actions at the end of the installation I configured dynamically the IIS to handler CGI using [the documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239230(v=ws.10).aspx), to configure FastCGI to Host PHP, Python, **Applications**. There are a lot of steps and development to achieve this results, but the problem is here:

I installed the application and everything works fine, but, if I uninstall or install another Instance or another WebApplication the handlers configure by IIS is like globally and always points to the first installed. (The problem occurs when I uninstall the application)
The *applicationHost.config* located in *C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config* that is the configuration of IIS has the "config" like global.

```
<handlers accessPolicy="Read, Script">
            <add name="PHP-FastCGI" path="*.php" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="E:\CIM_dev\bin\php-v5.6\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" />
            <add name="CGI-exe_2" path="*.exe" verb="*" modules="CgiModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Execute" allowPathInfo="true" />
            <add name="TRACEVerbHandler2" path="*" verb="TRACE" modules="ProtocolSupportModule" requireAccess="None" />
            <add name="OPTIONSVerbHandler2" path="*" verb="OPTIONS" modules="ProtocolSupportModule" requireAccess="None" />
            <add name="StaticFile2" path="*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read" />
        </handlers>
```

My question is, is there any way to do this configuration for each web site into the **web.config**? I've been trying all stuff without success.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So if I understand it right, you want to move php handlers from server/website level to individual applications. Why dont you add a web.config file within your php application folder and move the application specific handlers there.

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35332431/1766402 - check this answer (I am hoping you have CGI enabled in IIS?). To do this via wix, can you add the following command within a custom action and execute. This will unlock the parent config file.

> %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe unlock config "SiteName/app1"
>   -section:system.webServer/handlers

3. Within the PHP application folder (let's say c:\php\app1) create a web.config file with the following content:

> 

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>      
        <handlers>
            <add name="PHPviaFastCGI" path="*.php" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Users\axputhe\Documents\PHP\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

2. Now if you look at your application within IIS Manager you should see something like this (App Dir -> Handler Mappings)

[image]

Note "local" this confirms that the setting is coming from your local web.config and not from the applicationhost.config file.

Comment: I try this and always get: This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".

Comment: looks like your handler section is locked at parent level. Can you try the updated section in the answer?

Comment: This section can be unlocked in applicationHost.config but the goals is to avoid user intervention. As I said, I has try lots of tricks without success :(

Comment: Can you add the unlock command (that I added to the answer) within wix using a custom action?

Comment: @wrivas - can you confirm whether it worked? If it worked can you please mark it as the answer.

Comment: Yes, now I have another error but I can handle it. With the help of [https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/fastcgi] and you. Thank you