# Python web application installer packages?

Tags: python

Has anyone ever made an installer package for a Flask or Django (or other WSGI framework) application that lays down the code, virtualenv, configures the WSGI server (Gunicorn or uWSGI for example)? I've tried Googling the topic but I only find documentation about installing the frameworks themselves or deploying the applications to cloud services like AWS and Heroku.

I know that all of the above could be scripted, but I'm interested in building actual installer packages for different platforms that get the WSGI app up and running and leaves the other needed components (such as database, cache, proxy, etc.) up to the administrator.

Are there existing examples of this someone could point me to? Does anyone have suggestions on where to start for learning how to create these packages?

Comment: I made it for PHP on IIS. You must be familiar with WiX installer. Also, check my question about configuring the WSGI automatically:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42032454/php-or-whatever-cgi-configuration-in-web-config-iis

Comment: If you are looking for how to make it with Debian's package https://github.com/codeinthehole/django-in-a-deb-file/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just package the app as a [docker](https://www.docker.com/get-started) container?

Comment: That is how I do it now.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice this was such an old question when I answered.
But hey, it didn't have an answer, and now it does :D

Comment: Yeah, I never did come back around to this.