# Getting error happens when the section is locked at a parent level in VIS2019 in windows 10 with IIS Express

Tags: visual-studio, iis, web-config, iis-express

Im using this in my web.config in my VS2019 project with IIS express on windows 10.

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <authentication>
            <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
            <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />         
        </authentication>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

But I get this error

```
This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".
```

I looked at the internet to try different things, but none seem to work.

- https://digitaldrummerj.me/iis-express-windows-authentication/
- https://mpituley.wordpress.com/2016/10/04/http-error-500-19-in-the-iis-express/
- [Config Error: This configuration section cannot be used at this path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794985/config-error-this-configuration-section-cannot-be-used-at-this-path/44315944)
- [Config Error: This configuration section cannot be used at this path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794985/config-error-this-configuration-section-cannot-be-used-at-this-path)
- [Config Error: This configuration section cannot be used at this path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794985/config-error-this-configuration-section-cannot-be-used-at-this-path)
- [IIS Config Error - This configuration section cannot be used at this path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199976/iis-config-error-this-configuration-section-cannot-be-used-at-this-path)

I've modified the files

- C:\Users\me\Documents\project\.vs\config\applicationhost.config
- C:\Users\me\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config

I'm not sure what else to try.

Does anyone know?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is the IIS Express configuration / metabase file found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12946476/where-is-the-iis-express-configuration-metabase-file-found)

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, there was another file I had to edit

```
C:\Users\me\Documents\project\.vs\project\config\applicationhost.config
```